# group and count duplicates to a dictionary with linq

Tags: c#, linq

with the following list:

```
a
a
b
b
b
c
```

I would like to make, using linq, a dictionary that contains:

```
a => 2
b => 3
c => 1
```

for now I have:

```
var Q = (from l in List
        group l by l into g
        let Count = g.Count()
        select new { Key = g.Key, Value = Count})
```

How do I turn this to a dictionary?

Edit:
I changed the last line to:

```
select new Dictionary<string, int> { g.Key, Count });
```

but I still don't have the right syntax

Comment: [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)

Comment: select new Dictionary<type1, type2>(){};

Comment: .ToDictionary( g => g.Key, g => g.Count() );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to solution in fact. You can also solve it such;

```
    var query =
        from q in list
        group q by q into t
        select new
        {
            Key = t.Key,
            Value = t.Count()
        }; 
    var dict = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: thanks! I can never wrap my head around the linq syntax :)

Answer (score 5):

Just slap a `ToDictionary` after a `GroupBy`.

```
var counts = List.GroupBy(l => l)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
```

Answer (score -1):

This way Works to me

```
List<string> vs = new List<string> { "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b" };

        var output = vs.GroupBy(word => word).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).Select(group => group.Key);

        foreach (var item in output)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item + "=>" + item.Count() );
        }
```